# Excel Functions Not Working on Imported File

Tags: excel, csv, import

I have a .CSV which I imported into Excel using Data > From Text/CSV and selected semi-colon as my delimiter. The data looks fine.

When I attempt to sum(), countif(), etc on a range I get "0".

I have attempted:

Select all, format as numbers

Select all, copy, paste special - numbers only, on a new sheet

Save as .xlsx and reopen

Open new sheet, =sheet1!A1 and copy everything

None of this has worked.

Clue: The numbers were imported centered to the left of each cell. If I select a cell with a number, cursor to the number in the fx bar, hit enter, the number then shifts to the right of the cell and functions work just fine.

Comment: It means you have text that *looks* like numbers.  You should be able to copy -> pastespecial -> values to correct the issue.

Comment: Or enter 1 in a new cell, copy it, then select all your data and pastespecial > multiply. @tigeravatar I'm not sure pastespecial > values works.

Comment: @BigBen Ah, you're right. Doh

Comment: @BigBen Good idea, I think that would work, however now I have an error that there isn't enough memory to complete the action.

Comment: @BigBen The multiplication by 1 worked, I was able to do it on the column I needed. I will have to run the operation multiple times to convert the entire sheet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing your import.

```
Sub fixTextThatLookLikeNumbers()
    dim i as long

    with worksheets(1)
        for i=.cells(1, .columns.count).emd(xltoleft).column to 1 step -1
            with .columns(i)
                .texttocolumns destination:=.cells(1), _
                               datatype:=xlfixedwidth, fieldinfo:=array(0,1)
            end with
        next i
    end sub
end sub
```

Comment: I totally understand for loop,  but I have difficulties with the for each loop.  Could the above be done with a for each loop as well? or would it wind up doing every cell in the worksheet?

Comment: Probably something like `for each cell in intersect(.cells(1,1).currentregion, .rows(1))`